# how to edit areas In CRM DYNAMICS?

Tags: entity, crm, microsoft-dynamics, account, invoice

I'm new at CRM DYNAMICS and I need to know how to add an entity in another entity area and if it is possible ?
Like if I clicked in a specific account name the invoices should be shown as an option in its area like cases markiting lists ... etc

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks I just figured it out, we can do this from form editor of specific  entity and customizing the navigation bar and form it self.